# How does FineUI implement responsive UI?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, responsive-design

I am using FineUI MVC asp.net control lib, and they start to support responsive in V5.0. I am curious about their implementation so checked with their support team, they replied me with "pixel-based elegant design using javascript" instead of my imaged css media query. Not sure if anyone is using this library, or if there is any hint to help me figure out their implementation? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Their blog doesn't give much details
http://blog.fineui.us/2018/05/fineui-is-responsive-now.html

Comment: media query is the popular way to implement responsive like bootstrap, but how to use Javascript?